# Difference between int fpurge() and int fflush() in C

Tags: c, filestream, file-handling, fflush

Can anyone please explain me about difference between `fpurge(FILE *stream)` and `fflush(FILE *stream)` in C?
Both `fflush()` and `fpurge()` will discard any unwritten or unread data in the buffer.
Please explain me  the exact difference between these two and also their pros and cons.

Comment: Judging from the Linux manual page for [`fpurge()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge), one problem with `fpurge()` is that it is non-standard, being derived from BSD 4.4, so it is not available everywhere.  The Mac OS X (BSD) man page describes `fpurge()` but doesn't mention its provenance — though it does say that `fseek()`, list on the same page, conforms to Standard C so (by inference) `fpurge()` doesn't.

Comment: See also [How can I flush data from a tty input queue on a Unix system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938882/)

Answer (score 4):

"... both `fflush` and `fpurge` will discard any unwritten or unread data in the buffer..." : No.

- `fflush`:

  > The function `fflush` **forces a write** of all buffered data for the given output or update stream via the stream's underlying write function. The open status of the stream is unaffected.
  >   If the stream argument is `NULL`, `fflush` flushes all open output streams.
- `fpurge`:

  > The function `fpurge` **erases** any input or output buffered in the given stream. For output streams this discards any unwritten output. For input streams this discards any input read from the underlying object but not yet obtained via `getc`. This includes any text pushed back via `ungetc`. (P.S.: there also exists `__fpurge`, which does the same, but without returning any value).

Besides the obvious *effect on buffered data*, one use where you would notice the difference is with *input streams*. You can `fpurge` one such stream (although it is usually a mistake, possibly conceptual). Depending on the environment, you might not `fflush` an input stream (its behaviour might be undefined, see [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush)). In addition to the above remarked differences: 1) the cases where they lead to *errors* are different, and 2) `fflush` can work on all output streams with a single statement, as said (this might be very useful).

As for pros and cons, I would not really quote any... they simply work different (mostly), so you should know when to use each.

In addition to the *functional* difference (what you were asking), there is a *portability* difference: `fflush` is a standard function, while `fpurge` is not (and `__fpurge` is not either).

Here you have the respective man pages ([`fflush`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush), [`fpurge`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fpurge)).

Answer (score 2):

To start with, both the functions *clear* the buffers <sup>(*type of operable buffers are discussed below*)</sup>, the major difference is what happens with the data present in the buffer.

- For `fflush()`, the data is *forced to be written to disk*.
- For `fpurge()`, data is *discarded*.

That being said, `fflush()` is a standard C function, mentioned in the `C11`, chapter §7.21.5.2.

Whereas, `fpurge()` is a non-portable and non-standard function. From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fpurge.3.html)

> These functions are nonstandard and not portable.  The function
>          `fpurge()` was introduced in 4.4BSD and is not available under Linux.
>          The function `__fpurge()` was introduced in Solaris, and is present in
>          glibc 2.1.95 and later.

That said, the major usage-side difference is,

- Calling `fflush()` with input stream is  [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

  > If `stream` points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent
  >   operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that `stream`
  >   to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is
  >   undefined.**
- Calling `fpurge()` with input stream is defined.

  > For input streams
  >      this discards any input read from the underlying object but not yet
  >      obtained via `getc(3)`; this includes any text pushed back via
  >      `ungetc(3)`.

Still, try to stick to `fflush()`.

Comment: `fflush` on input streams may be left undefined by ISO C, but it is specified by POSIX. The effect is similar to that quoted for `fpurge` except that it only works on *seekable* input streams — i.e. it can be used to ensure that stale data wasn't buffered from a disk file, but not to discard data buffered from a pipe or tty.

Comment: @hobbs Right, but still, it's implementation defined.

Comment: ^^ I mean to say, the applicability of `fflush(stdin)`. IIRC, MSVC defines that, but a code with that line is certainly not _easily_ portable. :)

Comment: "Calling fflush() with input stream is undefined behavior." and "Calling fpurge() with input stream is defined." is not consistent.  Per the C standard `fflush(file_in_input_mode)` is UB and `fpurge()` is also not defined behavior given it is not in the standard.  Both of these are defined within Linux and other platforms.