# Code skipped when calling function from switch

Tags: c

I have a code that is suppose to ask a user for a car manufacturer and then store it inside a txt file (this is part of introductory course in C). I have the following menu for calling the function inside int main

```
while(1)
{
     printf("Choice");
     scanf("%i", &MENYVAL);
    switch(MENYVAL){
            case 1 : ADDVEHICLE();      break;
            case 2 : read();            break;
            default: printf("No choice was made");
    }
            printf("\tChoice");
            scanf("%i", &MENYVAL);
}
```

where "ADDVEHICLE" is the following function

```
void ADDVEHICLE() {
FILE *fp;
char CAR[50];

fp = fopen("FILE.txt", "a");

if(!fp) {
    printf("ERROR");
}

printf("\n Manufacturer");
fgets(CAR, sizeof(CAR), stdin);
fprintf(fp, "%s", CAR);

fclose(fp);}
```

When running the program and scanning "MENYVAL=1"
I get the output

```
Manufacturer Choice
```

I.e the code reads the print in ADDVEHICLE but then returns to the switch code in int main without asking for input.

Attempts: 
If I remove the switch code and just call the function ADDVEHICLE the code works fine, I can input text which is stored in the correct txt file.

I tested adding after "fprinf" the following code (which i believe tries to flush the buffer) see [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938882/how-can-i-flush-unread-data-from-a-tty-input-queue-on-a-unix-system) for inspiration:

```
while (!EOF) { fprintf(fp, "%s", "\t");}
```

with no success.

PS. I am programming on a linux VM but I am not sure if it is correct to use the tag, I apologize if the tag is incorrect

Comment: _'scanning "MENYVAL=1"'_ Do you mean this literally? Because your program only accepts a number, not a "MENUVAL=" prefix

Comment: There is no code shown in this question that can output "Manufacturer Choice". Present your [mcve].

Comment: _"the code reads the print in ADDVEHICLE but then returns to the switch code in int main without asking for input."_ We have no way of knowing what ADDVEHICLE does because you did not show it to us (there is instead ADDFORDON)

Comment: yes scanning the number 1, sorry for the confusion, I will edit that into the body of text

Comment: `scanf("%i", &MENYVAL);` leaves the newline in the buffer, so `fgets` scans empty.

Comment: @KamilCuk If you have an answer please put it in the answer section where it can undergo the normal peer review thank you

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you have any recommendation on how i can solve that? I am still not comfortable with programming and struggle with a lot of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the '\n' character, remaining after execution of `scanf()` before `switch`, is readed inside `ADDFORDON()` function by `fgets()` call. Add "buffer flusher" before `fgets()` like below:

```
void ADDVEHICLE() {
    FILE *fp;
    char CAR[50];

    fp = fopen("FILE.txt", "a");

    if (!fp) {
        printf("ERROR");
    }

    // flush buffer here!
    scanf("%s"); // this reads any characters remaining in input buffer then ignores them

    printf("\n Manufacturer");

    fgets(CAR, sizeof(CAR), stdin);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", CAR);

    fclose(fp);
}
```